# What was the specific function of the relay which captured Grace Hopper's famous "bug"?

Tags: history, bugs, relay-computer

Computer pioneer Grace Hopper often recounted the story of her team [finding the first physical computer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_hopper#Anecdotes):

> While she was working on a Mark II Computer at Harvard University in 1947, her associates discovered a moth that was stuck in a relay; the moth impeded the operation of the relay.  While neither Hopper nor her crew mentioned the phrase "debugging" in their logs, the case was held as an instance of literal "debugging."  For many years, the term *bug* had been in use in engineering. The remains of the moth can be found in the group's log book at the Smithsonian Institution's National Museum of American History in Washington, D.C.

The photo below of the log book states "Relay #70 Panel F".  **What precise function did this relay perform?**

[image: first computer bug]

Comment: This question might be "Are there schematics for the Mark II?"

Comment: @RETRAC: There are, in the [Grace Murray Hopper Collection](https://sova.si.edu/details/NMAH.AC.0324) of the Smithsonian.  Here are links to the [Mark II panel diagram](https://ids.si.edu/ids/deliveryService?id=NMAH-AC0324-0000072-02) and a badly-organized PDF of random pages from the [Mark II User's Manual](http://edan.si.edu/slideshow/viewer/pdf/download/e8e3adb347594eed612726e4e338fd20.pdf), with schematics of various parts.  However, I haven't yet found the relay in question.

Comment: _"What precise function did this relay perform?"_ - in this instance it caught a moth. Do you mean what function was the relay _supposed_ to perform?

Comment: @BruceAbbott wouldn't that make it a feature and not a bug?

Comment: I am not sure it is entirely meaningful to ask. A relay is a mechanical switch; it is either open or closed, that's it. So it can store 1 bit.

The Harvard Mark II was not a stored-program computer; it read instructions from a paper tape and did the calculations. It was a bit more like an automated calculator. So what did that one bit in its memory do? It stored one bit of a number, either one to be operated on or the output of an arithmetic operation. That's probably about as much as can be said.

Comment: @Liam, relays do much more than just storage, just as the transistors in modern machines aren't all in memory cells (registers, RAM, etc).  It's as likely to be in an i/o unit, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Parts of this answer are necessarily speculation, especially since the way the machine worked (and its bizarre programming model) are buried deep in time, or at least deep in various museums<sup>(1)</sup> :-)

First off, I have to say this behemoth was truly a thing of beauty. The way it was programmed was with a paper tape with each instruction holding parts (practically RISC/VLIW in the general approach):

- which devices would output to the "bus";
- which devices would input from the "bus"; and
- an operation which would be executed or started.

All uses of the calculator boiled down to a sequence of simple operations like adding, multiplying, interpolation, and function calculations. These were used in conjunction with "constant" registers that would use these operations for specific tasks.

The whole thing was driven by a (very mechanical) sequencing unit, using motors and gears to advance the paper tape and use the current tape "instruction" to control every other part of the machine. Hence it was, for all intents and purposes, the clock signal in modern computers:

[image]

It appears it was even multi-core since you could dedicate the entire calculator to one task or use the duplication on right and left to do two calculations concurrently.

---

The following layout shows the various parts of the system.

[image]

On the other side of the main "winged" control panel stood the six rather large relay cubicles, which each contained various panels, including panel `F` in the third relay cubicle, where the moth in question met its glorious and famous end. A non-layout view of the left three relay cubicles (and the left wing) is shown here:

[image]

That panel `F` in the layout did not have a more mathematically obvious labels (such as `ADDER`, `MULTIPLIER`, or `INTERPOLATOR`). Instead, panels `F` and `G` were both labelled `SEQUENCE`, and panel `E2` was `TRANSFERS AND JUMPS`.

So they were all probably responsible for program or data flow, such as controlling flow of information between various other panels, or somehow affecting the "clock generator" shown above.

> The image of a `JUMP` instruction causing a motor/gear combo to back the paper tape up a few feet, rather then just changing the instruction pointer register, seems particularly funny to me (I have no idea how loops were actually done, that thought just popped into my head as one possibility).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that all images and most research in this answer has come from either:

- the Grace Hopper online exhibitions at the Smithsonian; or
- the Computer History Museum in California.

I'm not affiliated with them in any way but I urge you to visit (or otherwise support) them if you're interested in retro-computing, *especially* if you're interested in times before the unholy trinity. I visited the CHM about a decade ago and still *plan* to visit the Smithsonian at some point in the future, assuming the chances of a treasonous insurrection during my visit can be minimised :-)

Comment: If JUMP relied on moving the tape, then a tight loop could be quite expensive. How did they optimize loops back then? Were they unrolling the loop already back then? Or was there a "loop buffer", e.g. a drum or circular tape loop?

Comment: Sorry, @user3528438, I meant that as a joke (and have now clarified in the answer). I'm not sure how loops were actually done.